# Forcing url forwarded to http when enabling SSL for Joomla Login Module

Tags: ssl, joomla

I was enabling "Encrypt Login Form" for my joomla website but after user logging in, it always forwarded to https:// url. Is there any easy way to force forwarded url to use http:// ? So the ssl will be used for login or registration purpose only?
Thanks

Comment: Encrypting the login form is specifically for this purpose, so why would you want to change the url from https:// to http:// ? If you don't want this, then simply disable it.

Comment: I want to make ssl available for com_user only (for login and registration). Enabling ssl on the login module changes all url's in joomla to https